# JavaScript - Are numbers ordered Kata

Tags: javascript

I'm a recent coding bootcamp student, I graduated on Friday. Whilst i'm looking for my first career opportunity, I've been looking back at some of the early katas we were given to develop our problem solving skills, and I have to say I've been stumped by a few of them. I've written the tests for these problems and used TDD to try and solve them. The language is Javascript.

Can anyone kindly point me in the right direction with this. I've written 4 tests, it's passing 3 out of the 4, I can't get it to pass the 3rd test, and I'm not sure what else to try.

Kata Instructions:
  the areOrdered function should take an array of numbers as an input.
  It should return true if all the numbers are in ascending order and false if they are not.
  An empty array should return false.

My tests:

```
const areOrdered = require("../katas/are-ordered");
const { expect } = require("chai");

describe.only("areOrdered", () => {
  it("returns a boolean", () => {
    const nums = [];
    const actualResults = areOrdered(nums);
    const expectedResults = false;
    expect(actualResults).to.equal(expectedResults);
  });

  it("returns false if passed an empty array", () => {
    const nums = [];
    const actualResults = areOrdered(nums);
    const expectedResults = false;
    expect(actualResults).to.equal(expectedResults);
  });

  it("returns true if the numbers array is in ascending order", () => {
    const nums = [1, 2, 3];
    const actualResults = areOrdered(nums);
    const expectedResults = true;
    expect(actualResults).to.equal(expectedResults);
  });
  it("returns false if the numbers array is not in ascending order", () => {
    const nums = [3, 1, 0, 2];
    const actualResults = areOrdered(nums);
    const expectedResults = false;
    expect(actualResults).to.equal(expectedResults);
  });
});
```

My solution:

```
function areOrdered(nums) {
  if (nums.length === 0) {
    return false;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if (!nums[i] < nums[i] + 1) {
      return false;
    } else if (nums[i] < nums[i] + 1) {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Results:

areOrdered

```
✓ returns a boolean
✓ returns false if passed an empty array
1) returns true if the numbers array is in ascending order
✓ returns false if the numbers array is not in ascending order
```

3 passing (11ms)
  1 failing

1) areOrdered
       returns true if the numbers array is in ascending order:

```
  AssertionError: expected false to equal true
  + expected - actual

  -false
  +true
```

Comment: `nums[i] + 1` should be `nums[i + 1]` (with a check to ensure that you're not overflowing the end of your array).

Comment: also, parentheses are your friend.  `!nums[i] < nums[i] + 1` is very different from `!(nums[i] < nums[i] + 1)`.

Comment: do you have a link to the kata?

Comment: `!` has precedence over `<`.

Comment: Thank you, I had a feeling it might be something simple like brackets or a syntax mistake. Think i’d just been staring at it too long and couldn’t see it. Thanks for the input everyone I’ll have another crack at it shortly.

Comment: Hi Nina, I’ve posted the kata just above the ‘My tests’ bit in my original post. Sorry it’s not hosted anywhere online, it’s just a VS Code file on my laptop that I can was given from my course, so I’ve just had to copy and paste the text onto here. Hope it reads ok, please let me know if not. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate from the second item and check the item before and the actual item.

Return `false` if the values are not in order.

At the end return `true`.

```js
function areOrdered(nums) {
    if (nums.length === 0) return false;

    for (let i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (nums[i - 1] >= nums[i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

console.log(areOrdered([]));           // false
console.log(areOrdered([1, 2, 3]));    //  true
console.log(areOrdered([3, 1, 0, 2])); // false
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do that like this:

```
function areOrdered(nums) {
  if (nums.length === 0) return false;

  let sorted = nums.concat().sort((a, b) => a-b);
  let isSorted = true;
  for(let i in sorted)
    if(sorted[i] !== nums[i] && isSorted) isSorted = false;
  return isSorted;
}
```

Just copy array and sort with Array.sort() and then compare it to original one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions everyone. It’s great to know that there’s more than one way of solving it.